# location.href not redirecting inside jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Im using javascript, jquery and jquery mobile.
I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#routes").change(function(){
        var newValue = $("#routes").val();
        if(newValue != -1){
            newLocation="http://localhost:8080/map.jsp?route="+newValue ;
            window.location.href=newLocation;
        }
    });
});
```

But the location.href is not redirecting me.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I got this and its working now, my problem now is that map.jsp is not going executing the .ready event:

```
        $.mobile.changePage('/map.jsp', {
            reloadPage: true,
            type: "get",
            data: 'route='+newValue
        });
```

Comment: Does the statement execute, or does `....+valor` throw an error?

Comment: Yes, but nothing happens. It shows the loader on the browser tab but nothing happens.

Comment: Are the page and the target page served from th same domain? If so, then try using a relative URL. If not, it could be a browser security model violation due to trying to access localhost.

Comment: What contain the "valor" var and what did you do with newValue ? In your code, newValue is not used..

Comment: Sorry, I translated the code to post the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Hogan Answer he is right just use

`window.location = newLocation; return false;`  because i ran same problem and using just **window.location** solved my problem.

And one more thing you might need to look for is # in the end of url i don't know but having # at the end of url not redirecting when you use `window.location`.

Hope this will help.

Comment: +1 : Because you said I was right (which I knew, but it is always nice to hear.)

Answer (score 0):

use just

```
window.location=newLocation;
```

Comment: window.location is a "Location" object. You can assign a string buts it is a best effort behaviour and I dont think this is solving the problem in this case. window.location.href represent the complete URL and can be read and set to change the location.

Comment: @user1073122 - You are wrong >> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location

Comment: "Returns a Location object" I wrote my comment regarding this article. I know that window.location can be used as string buts its a best effort, and it not the solution to the problem.

Comment: @user1073122 - You did not read far enough -- the first example shows setting the window location with a string as above.  In addition, this is the most x-browser compatible way to do it.